# Random variables associated to real values

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Reading the answer of this question (which is very good), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/example-of-sample-x-1-x-2-ldots-x-n/141574#comment846751_141574, I realised that there is a point I don't understand. I quote bullet point two:

- such an experiment can be, e.g.: pick a random person in Paris and measure them. The output is a size. Each particular experiment leads a size $x$, which is a real number. $\underline{\textit{We denote $X$ the random variable which is associated }}$; $X$ is not a number. A way to see it is as function from the set $\Omega$ of all possible experiment results, in our case the set of Parisians, to the real numbers. In this optic, a random variable is a measure done on a random experiment.

The underlined sentence is what I don't understand. How this random variable $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined? In other words, given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, that is interpreted as a height of a Parisian, how the corresponding random variable $X$ is be defined (or, constructed)? I'm not necessarily talking about explicit formula (if a "natural" map exists of course will be happy to see it), but the rationale behind this identification.

As a sidenote, I'm aware of the realisation of a random variable and I understand that given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for the associated random variable we mean that $X(\omega)=x$, for some $\omega \in \Omega$. What I don't understand is how $X(\omega^{\prime})$ should be understood, for $\omega^{\prime} \neq \omega$.

Comment: A function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is defined by a prescription. Every $\omega\in\Omega$ is sent (or is connected) with some element of $\mathbb R$ which is denoted by $X(\omega)$. In this case $\omega$ is an inhabitant of Paris and $X(\omega)$ is the length of this inhabitant. It seems that you want to go the other way around: "giving $x\in\mathbb R$,....how the corresponding rv $X$ is to be defined?" If $\omega,\omega'\in\Omega$ with $\omega\neq\omega'$ then we are dealing with two distinct inhabitants of Paris (eventually having different length).

Comment: @drhab thank you for your comment. yes that's exactly what I don't understand. Since we are talking about a random variable associated to $x \in \mathbb{R}$, this $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ must be unique in some sense. In algebra for example we would use the term "natural" to describe the nature of this $X$, meaning that under some natural identification we "see" the scalar $x$ as a map etc.. How can we do the same in that context?

Comment: I do not see the sense of speaking of "a random variable associated to $x\in\mathbb R$". It can at most be that some $\omega\in\Omega$ exists with $X(\omega)=x$ but that says at most that $x$ is in the range of $X$. Why speaking of an "association"?

Comment: @drhab it comes from the underlined sentence I quoted from another question. The answer contains the word associated. That's why I wrote it.

Comment: @drhab equivalently, I have seen many people saying, "assume $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a random sample and let $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ denote their corresponding variables". What are these $X_i$'s and how do they correspond to the scalars $x_i$'s.

Comment: I think that is especially a statistical way of speaking. I (probability rather than statistics) would always start with the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ that - for a special $\omega\in\Omega$ - have taken the values $x_1=X_1(\omega),\dots,x_n=X_n(\omega)$.

Comment: Instead of writing out comments, would you like to move to  a discussion for one minute? Equivalently, you can write an answer if you want?

Comment: Actually rather not a further discussion. I would rather leave it here. Further on forehand I reckoned that I would be "incomplete". That's why I choose for commenting and not answering. Maybe a better crossing "probability-theorist/statistician" will give you a satisfying answer. Cheers.